# group by and multiple all the values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What's the best way to implement the product of a group of values?

```
select Col1, multiple(V) -- returns v1*v2*...*vn
from Table
group by Col1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can fake a `product()` aggregate function by doing the following](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/the-aggregate-function-product/):

```
SELECT Col1, EXP(SUM(LOG(V)))
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1
```

Why does this work?

Take the following example:

```
DECLARE @x INT, @y INT

SET @x = 7
SET @y = 8

-- Both return 4.02535
PRINT LOG(@x * @y)
PRINT LOG(@x) + LOG(@y)

-- Both return 56.
PRINT EXP(LOG(@x) + LOG(@y))
PRINT @x * @y
```

So for logarithms, `LOG(x * y) = LOG(x) + LOG(y)`... and since we have a `SUM()` function but lack a `PRODUCT()` function, if we pass each value to `LOG()` and then `SUM()` these results, it would be equivalent to multiplying every value and then passing the result to `LOG()`.

Finally, `EXP()` is performed against the `SUM()` to reverse the `LOG()`.

There are some stipulations for this to work correctly though... such as every value must be greater than zero.